# How can I write code that needs to run after some gem was loaded, but without requiring that gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, dynamic-loading

I am writing a gem that "hooks" onto other gems. It's designed to work with multiple different gems that do similar things, this adds functionality onto any of them that may be present.

What my gem does at startup is something like this:

```
if defined?(GemAModule)
  # Hook onto Gem A's observer methods
end

if defined?(GemBModule)
  # Hook onto Gem B's observer methods
end
```

Because of this, I need this code to run *after* A and / or B have been loaded. But I can't require either A or B. I want this to work for people that use only A, or only B, so A and B are not in my gem's dependencies, and they can't be in require statements.

I could do this by having a: `MyGem.hook()` method that users call in their initializers, after they have initialized A or B or both. But I'm trying to avoid that. I want to have it so that adding my gem just "magically" work.

Is this possible? What is the best way to do this?

Can I somehow check if "a gem is in the gemfile", and in that case require the module?

Answer (score 1):

You could make this work in the case where your gem is loaded first by overriding `require`. Combined with your code that works in the case when your gem is loaded after the other gems, this should solve the problem. Something like this:

```
module Kernel
  alias original_require require

  def require(name)
    if original_require(name)
      case name
      when 'gem_A'
        # stuff goes here
      when 'gem_B'
        # more stuff goes here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I personally would do in this situation is have your users `require` your gem in different ways depending on which other gem they are using, for example:

```
# if using gem A
require 'gem_A'
require 'your_gem/gem_A_compat'

# if using gem B
require 'gem_B'
require 'your_gem/gem_B_compat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't auto-detect code setup, or do anything overly complicated or "clever", you will regret it when it comes to testing and debugging (you will need both compatible gems in your development dependencies and have tests that load each in turn). Instead, document your own gem's `require`s so that the end user loads your gem depending on the link they wish to make.

So, assuming your gem is called `my_gem`, you would have files:

*lib/my_gem/gem_a.rb*

```
require 'my_gem'
require 'gem_a'
# Require Hook onto Gem A's observer methods
```

*lib/my_gem/gem_b.rb*

```
require 'my_gem'
require 'gem_b'
# Require Hook onto Gem B's observer methods
```

And you instruct the end user to `require` your gem as follows:

```
require 'my_gem/gem_a'
```

or . . .

```
require 'my_gem/gem_b'
```

as needed.

This is no more work for your gem user, and a lot easier to test, develop and debug for you and developers that use your gem.